# ¿Cómo iniciar otra actividad al hacer click en imagen de RecyclerView?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, recyclerview, onclicklistener

Logro hacer que abra la segunda actividad pero lo hace presionando cualquier imagen, yo quiero que se abra haciendo click solo en una imagen en especifico, por ejemplo presionando la imagen_1

```
    class InicioAdapter (private val context: Context, private val dataset: List<Inicio>):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<InicioAdapter.InicioViewHolder>(){

    class InicioViewHolder(private val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_title_inicio)
        val imageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_image_inicio)
    
      /** Aqui */
      init {
            view.setOnClickListener {
                val irConstruccion = Intent(view.context, ConstruccionActivity::class.java)
                view.context.startActivity(irConstruccion)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): InicioViewHolder {

        val adapterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_inicio, parent, false)

        return InicioViewHolder(adapterLayout)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: InicioViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = dataset[position]
        holder.textView.text = context.resources.getString(item.stringResourceId)
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(item.imageResourceId)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = dataset.size
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo usanso getAdapterPosition, buscas la posición y mediante un condicional le dices que abra la actividad con esa imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente asigna el listener  a tu ImageView despuès de obtener su referencia:

```
 class InicioViewHolder(private val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_title_inicio)
        val imageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.item_image_inicio)
    
    
      init {
            imageView.setOnClickListener { //* Asigna listener a ImageView
                val irConstruccion = Intent(view.context, ConstruccionActivity::class.java)
                view.context.startActivity(irConstruccion)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: El problema es que abre la nueva actividad presionando cualquier imagen de mi RecyclerView, y necesito que la abra presionando solo la primer imagen del Recycler